# CakePHP 3.5 is broken by Google Analytics PHP 2.0 when installed by Composer?

Tags: php, cakephp, google-analytics

After attempting to create my own simple analytics tools and not being pleased with how they performed, today I attempted to import the Google Analytics PHP API in order to use that under CakePHP 3.5.

However, I have now installed both systems - CakePHP 3.5 and google/apiclient:^2.0 twice, and twice the installation has broken CakePHP, resulting in white pages. Each time it seems as if the composer Google install breaks existing files under the Vendor folder.

Has anyone had any success in integrating the Google Analytics PHP API with CakePHP 3.5?

Comment: "white page" usually means debug mode is set to `false`, which will make it difficult to debug.

Comment: That's part of it, debug has been set to true. It seems to not be rendering at all when I have the Google Analytics elements installed.

Comment: Based on the behavior I've seen, I think the Composer installation overwrites some of Cake's own needed files with versions it isn't recognizing. I'll try manually placing the PHP API next.

Comment: Check your Server/PHP/CakePHP logs, and use a proper debugger like Xdebug if necessary.

Comment: Well, trying the Composer route one more time has resulted in this: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Application' not found in /home/chroma/public_html/webroot/index.php on line 37

Comment: If I am reading the material I've found between the CookBook and Google's own correctly, I'm going to have to include the autoloader manually.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! It took a very careful reinstall, making sure Composer's files were in place and then putting everything else back in on top of the CakePHP / Google installation. That seems to have been the problem - missing Composer files.